# Added Tire search gem, how to add multiple indexes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a song.rb model and a genre.rb model that I'd like to be able to search.

For some reason Tire is only returning search results for songs and not genres.

**The code:**

```
genre.rb

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genre_songs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :songs, through: :genre_songs

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks


end
```

**song_controller snippit**

```
def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @songs = Song.search(params[:query], load: true)
    elsif params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    else      
      @songs = Song.order('id').order('plusminus desc nulls last').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15) 
      #@songs = Song.tally.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    end
  end
```

**song.rb snippit**

```
include Tire::Model::Search include Tire::Model::Callbacks
```

**index.html.erb snippit**

```
<%= form_tag songs_path, method: :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in controller:

```
  @songs = Song.search(params)
```

in song model:

```
  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 15) do
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?

    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(methods: [:genre_names])
  end

  def genre_names
    genres.map{ |g| g.name}   
  end
```